# Laravel etrepat/baum How to show whole tree

Tags: php, laravel, navigation, eloquent

how can I show the whole tree. I have a 3 Level Navigation (First is root). With that code, I will only see the 2nd Level.

```
$tree = \App\Category::where('identifier', 'soccer')->first();
foreach($tree->getDescendants()->toHierarchy() as $descendant) {
  echo "{$descendant->name} <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole tree including root by doing:

```
$root = Table::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
$tree = $root->getDescendantsAndSelf()->toHierarchy();
```

Now as $tree is Tree structure you need to traverse it recursively or with a queue data structure (DFS or BFS). Each item on the tree will have a children property with its children

Some pseudo for traversing would be:

```
function traverseBFS(tree) {
   q = Queue()
   q.push(tree[0]);
   while (!q.empty()) {
       item = q.top(); q.pop();
       // do what you need with item

       foreach (item->children as child) {
           q.push(child);
       }
   }
}
```